# MySql select next lower number without using limit

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to select the next lower number from a table without using limit.

Eg: If my table had `10, 3, 2 , 1` I'm trying to `select * from table where col > 10`.

The result I'm expecting is `3`. I know I can use limit 1, but can it be done without that?

Comment: `where col > 10` selects all records where the value for `col` is greater than 10, this is not wat you want. Also, what is the query for the first result? I assume you use an `order by`, otherwise you can't be sure about the order of your result set

Comment: Yes, I use order by desc

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(no) no
  FROM table1
 WHERE no < 10
```

Output:

```
| NO |
------
|  3 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9478/1)**

Comment: I checked. Amazing approach :)

Comment: This will only work for 10 but if there is 9 then how you will get 3.

Comment: @JDeveloper - OP wants *next lower number* so if there is 9 in the record then the desired result should be 9 not 3.

Comment: @JDeveloper OP's requirements says just get me next lowest, so in case there is 9 you get 9

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM
   (SELECT 
      @rid:=@rid+1 as rId,
      a.*
   FROM 
      tbl a
   JOIN
      (SELECT @rid:=0) b
   ORDER BY 
      id DESC)tmp
WHERE rId=2;
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/556bc/2)**:

```
| RID | ID |    TYPE |     DETAILS |
------------------------------------
|   2 | 28 | Twitter | @sqlfiddle5 |
```

Another approach

```
select a.* from supportContacts a inner join 
(select max(id) as id
from supportContacts
where 
id in (select id from supportContacts where id not in 
       (select max(id) from supportContacts)))b
on a.id=b.id
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/556bc/8)**:

```
| ID |    TYPE |     DETAILS |
------------------------------
| 28 | Twitter | @sqlfiddle5 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this query will always get the second highest number based on the inner where clause.

```
SELECT  *
FROM
        (
            SELECT  t.col, 
                    (
                        SELECT COUNT(distinct t2.col) 
                        FROM tableName t2 
                        WHERE t2.col >= t.col
                    ) as rank
            FROM    tablename t
            WHERE   col <= 10
        ) xx
WHERE   rank = 2             -- <<== means second highest
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/854ab/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*supports duplicate values*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ef4a/1)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get next lower number from table

you can get it with this query:

```
SELECT distinct col FROM table1 a 
WHERE  2 = (SELECT count(DISTINCT(b.col)) FROM table1 b WHERE a.col >= b.col);
```

later again if you want to get third lower number you can just pass 3 in place of 2 in where clause

again if you want to get second higher number, just change the condition of where clause in inner query with

```
a.col <= b.col
```