# MySQL: get next closest value out of in-list

Tags: mysql, sql

For the following table:

```
attr1       date
================
a     2016-12-21
a     2016-11-15
a     2015-04-15
b     2016-10-15
b     2013-10-15
b     2011-10-15
c     2015-01-01
d     2014-02-02
```

I want to get the row where attr1 = a and date = max(inputDate x) with x <= date.

And additionally the same for attr1 = b and input date y - and several other attributes and dates.

For a single date value, a solution is something like:

```
SELECT MAX(no) no
FROM table1
WHERE no < 10
```

(see:
[MySql select next lower number without using limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602651/mysql-select-next-lower-number-without-using-limit))

**Question:**

How is it possible to solve this with a single select and so that the dates (x, y, ...) and requested attr1 values are each in a `:list` of entries - it should be something like:

```
select * from table where attr1 in (..., ..., ...) .... and date in (x, y, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have the parameter list in a subquery:

```
select mytable.attr1, max(mytable.dt)
from
(
  select 'a' as attr1, '2015-11-20' as dt
  union all
  select 'b' as attr1, '2015-11-19' as dt
  union all
  select 'c' as attr1, '2015-11-18' as dt
  union all
  select 'd' as attr1, '2013-01-01' as dt
) params
join mytable on mytable.attr1 = params.attr1 and mytable.dt >= params.dt
group by mytable.attr1;
```

Comment: This doesn't get you the closest date by the way. I suppose you either want `mytable.dt <= params.dt` or `min(mytable.dt)`.

Comment: as I have to supply up to 180 dates, only a "where date in :list" approach will work properly.. :-(

Comment: What does "will work properly" mean? Above query should work, no matter whether you have two dates or two thousand dates in it. You can also use a temporary table and fill it with the dates instead, if you prefer so.